# How can I test if a field has been assigned to a channel?

Tags: field

I've got a generic template that can display entries from different channels. How in the template can I test if a field has been has been assigned to any given channel?

Comment: Why not check for the field's existence in an entry?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Twig has a "is defined" test that you can apply to a variable to see if it exists:

```
{% if entry.possibleField is defined %}
    Yup!
{% else %}
    Nope!
{% endif %}
```

And here is [more](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html) information on using `is defined`.